# IP Address is only 1 period

Tags: htaccess, ip-address

IP Address is only **1 period** on a shared host.  How do I block that in htaccess?

**The IP Shows: .**

/blog/

1/30/15 11:56 AM

success 200

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0

Comment: IP addresses are never just one period. Where are you getting this information from? Why do you want to block it?

Comment: I get it from time to time; its a bad bot or hacker?  Today the target was the blog & contact form.

Comment: Does your app support IPV6? Are you using any reverse proxy or other middle layers? Other than server side, there is no way to "rewrite" REMOTE_ADDR to just a period like that. I would suspect an error (or server side exploit) over an actual IP of period.

Comment: It's a small HTML5 site w/ a PHP shell & includes, no db. No IPV6

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^\.$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! now the hard part waiting to backhand 'em ;}

Comment: @EastTexas Let me know how it goes. If we need to make adjustments, we will!

Comment: Probably need to remove the _inline_ comments. These are deprecated. On later versions of Apache this will result in a 500 internal server error. Minor tidy up... no need for the `NC` flag when checking a dot. The `L` flag is also unnecessary when specifying the `F` flag; it is implied.

Comment: @w3d Thanks for the tips! I cut and pasted from a more complex example and probably was a bit brain dead. In-line comments depreciated?? I probably have a few. I put them in for the OPs understanding. I will avoid this in the future. I will always yield to your expertise. I do not do .htaccess stuff as much anymore, but what I do is rather tricky and not the norm for most. Updated the answer. Thanks again!!

Comment: Actually, I say _deprecated_, but I'm not sure that line-end (inline) comments have ever been "supported"! Only full line comments are allowed. Line-end comments won't always break, however, it depends on the directive (the arguments supplied), the module, the server. To be honest I used to use them, until I changed server and it unexpectedly broke! Both the [Apache 1.3](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/configuring.html) and [Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#syntax) docs state "Comments may **not** be included on a line after a configuration directive."

Comment: @w3d Good to know!! I will be changing any I might have still hanging around today. I did a significant clean-up of my .htaccess code since my seudo CMS software that I wrote is handling more of this internally now days. I am running the newest version of Apache since I was forced to update the OS last September. I installed the latest - greatest. It was Apache 2.2 before the update and now there is another OS update that I must apply before updating anything else. Frustrating!

Comment: The DOT has not returned, everything else is working like .ru, .cn, .ua, .nl & others are still being swatted down.   Is everyone else getting lots of bot/hacker from DigitalOcean, DataShack, DataPipe, Leaseweb?

Comment: @EastTexas Yes! Everyone likely is but often does not know it. ;-) As part of what I do, I study these things. You are getting bots from non-subscriber IP address pools. Many of these hosts are rather permissive and do not vet their customer base and as a result people who are up to no good often use them. These are generally not user based IP address pools so it is likely safe to block if you want. You can use the same code just do something like %{REMOTE_HOST} ^*\.example\.com$ and %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.0\.1\.102%.

Comment: DigitalOcean, DataShack, DataPipe, Leaseweb IP Ranges were blocked a few months back!  Leaseweb might be the worse of the bunch?

Comment: @EastTexas You said it brother! LeaseWeb is fairly permissive. OVH, eNOM and NameCheap are bad too. In fact, eNom appears in my database 4x greater than the next abusive IP address space.